# FetchXml optimization

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am looking for the ways how to optimize bulk download of CRM2011 data. Here are the two main scenarios:

a) Full synchronization: Download of all data - first all accounts, then all contacts etc etc.

b) Incremental synchronization: Download of all entities modified since given date

We use multithread downloader with 3 threads. Each thread performs FetchXml for one entity type that is downloaded page by page. Parsed objects are stored in the downloader cache and the downloader goes on for the next page. There is another thread that pulls the downloaded data from the cache and processes them. This organization increases the download speed more than 2x.

The problems I see:

a) FetchXml protocol is very inefficient. For example it contains lots of unneeded data. Example: FormattedValues take 10-15% bandwidth (my data show ~15% in the source Xml stream or ~10% in the zipped stream), although all we do with it is a) Xml parsing, b) throwing away. (Note that the parsing is not negligible either - iOs/Android Mono parsers are surprisingly slow.)

b) In case of incremental synchronization most of the FetchXml requests return zero items. In this case it would be highly desirable to combine several FetchXml requests into one. (AFAIK it is impossible.) Or maybe use another trick such as to ask for the counts of modified objects I did not investigate what is possible yet.

Does anybody have any advice how to optimize FetchXml traffic?

Comment: Is there a reason that you have to do direct calls to CRM? If you created a proxy web service and returned your response in JSON you would get a more bandwidth efficient transaction.

Comment: The reason is less work: The application I am talking about is very complex (online/offline mode, reports, editing, security, remote configurator etc). I think the middleware server would have to be rather complex, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your fastest method would be to use SQL server directly for something like this (unless you are using online).

To make the incremental faster, your best bet is to use the aggregate functionality FetchXML provides which is both extremely quick and less verbose.

Why parse on the iOS/Android Mono?  If you are instead sharing this to a large number of devices, you'd be better off having a central caching server that could send back this data in a json (zipped) format to the devices (or possibly bson).  Then the caching server would request an update of the changes, process those and then send back incremental changes in whatever format to the clients.  Would be considerably faster on the clients and far less bandwidth.

Comment: It is a mobile CRM client working under iOS/Android/WP/PPC/WinRT/Windows, online mode is an option. Hence SqlServer can't be used.

Comment: Ad: your best bet is to use the aggregate functionality... I am not sure how this would help. Incremental mode typically returns empty result sets except a few entities with a few objects. If I asked for counts first, then the actual number of web calls would actually increase, because I would have to download new/modified entities in an extra call. I think the rule one entity type per fetch applies also to aggregates, doesn't it?

Comment: Ad: central caching server... json might be better (I have no experience with it) as FetchXml is extremaly inefficient. Zip is no argument as zipping is done also with FetchXml. However, middleware server would complicate the things too much - for example already mentioned online mode.

Comment: @JanSlodicka My point about aggregates is speed; they are much faster to both execute and process.  It will increase your query count, but total performance should improve.  Instead of a middleware server, what about using an entity/plugin approach for this?  For example, if you want contacts updated since 3/3/2014 11:00 PM.  You'd create a record with the entity and datetime.  On create, the plugin would fire and save back to the record a JSON value of the data.  You'd then retrieve the record with the JSON data.  You could use more threads than 3 and push more heavy lifting off the client.

Comment: @entity/plugin approach: Interesting approach, never thought of it. However, I see several problems. a) Column set queried is not constant. For example entity lists in the online mode use less columns. b) Even if we stay in the offline mode (downloaded records are cached in the local DB) the remote configurator may change the list of entity columns that are cached on the client. c) Different clients might be configured to use different column sets.

Comment: @aggregates: Can you explain where you see the speed advantage? Do you mean that returning an empty resultset is slower than returning aggregate count 0? So far I was under the impression that 90% of the time is spent on the wire and that the packets of approximately same size take roughly the same time. (Well, the aggregate response is probably slightly smaller, should that matter that much?)

Comment: Well to follow up on the aggregates, I'm disappointed.  Testing 250 entities 2,000 times using a retrieve all columns method versus a count (select *), I found the aggregate to only provide a 12% speed improvement.  I would say the aggregate route would be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a way to further optimize FetchXML.  I would question why you're not using the OData Endpoints and REST, especially if you're primarily concerned with the about of data being sent over the wire.

I have talked to some brilliant CRM MVPs, and I know they have used REST to migrate data to CRM.  I'm not sure if they did it because it was faster, but I assumed that was why.

I do know that you are going to minimize the amount of data that is being sent to the client, since XML is extremely bloated.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know - the project used FetchXml, when I joined. That doesn't mean that it couldn't be changed, but there must be a strong reason for doing so. I have heard that OData should be faster (don't know how much). But I also noticed rumors about problems with ActivityParties (we need them) or large data sets.

Comment: If you are looking at CRM 2013 vs all versions of 2011, then I'd opt for the OData endpoint as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ExecuteMultipleRequest to allow you to perform multiple requests/queries at once... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executemultiplerequest.aspx